# Go detects concurrent read and write on map despite locks

Tags: go, synchronization

I'm writing a simple caching mechanism which has an `Add` an `Evict` and a `Search` method. The `Search` is currently not implemented yet, so there's no need to worry about that.

There's a relatively large number of goroutines that call `Add` to add data and there's only one which runs in an evict loop to evict data. As soon as I put some serious traffic on it Go throws up saying there's a concurrent read and write access on the map `metricCache`, but I can't see how that can happen because there are locks around it. I'm using Go 1.7.

File `mdata/cache.go`:

```
57: func NewCCache() *CCache {
58:     cc := &CCache{
59:         lock:        sync.RWMutex{},
60:         metricCache: make(map[string]*CCacheMetric),
61:         accnt:       accnt.NewFlatAccnt(maxSize),
62:     }
63:     go cc.evictLoop()
64:     return cc
65: }
66:
67: func (c *CCache) evictLoop() {
68:     evictQ := c.accnt.GetEvictQ()
69:     for target := range evictQ {
70:         c.evict(target)
71:     }
72: }
73: 
74: func (c *CCache) Add(metric string, prev uint32, itergen chunk.IterGen) {
75:     c.lock.Lock()
76: 
77:     if ccm, ok := c.metricCache[metric]; !ok {
78:         var ccm *CCacheMetric
79:         ccm = NewCCacheMetric()
80:         ccm.Init(prev, itergen)
81:         c.metricCache[metric] = ccm
82:     } else {
83:         ccm.Add(prev, itergen)
84:     }
85:     c.lock.Unlock()
86: 
87:     c.accnt.AddChunk(metric, itergen.Ts(), itergen.Size())
88: }
89: 
90: func (c *CCache) evict(target *accnt.EvictTarget) {
91:     c.lock.Lock()
92: 
93:     if _, ok := c.metricCache[target.Metric]; ok {
94:         log.Debug("cache: evicting chunk %d on metric %s\n", target.Ts, target.Metric)
95:         length := c.metricCache[target.Metric].Del(target.Ts)
96:         if length == 0 {
97:             delete(c.metricCache, target.Metric)
98:         }
99:     }
100: 
101:     c.lock.Unlock()
102: }
```

That's the error message:

```
metrictank_1    | fatal error: concurrent map read and map write
metrictank_1    | 
metrictank_1    | goroutine 3159 [running]:
metrictank_1    | runtime.throw(0xaade7e, 0x21)
metrictank_1    |       /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:566 +0x95 fp=0xc4216a7eb8 sp=0xc4216a7e98
metrictank_1    | runtime.mapaccess2_faststr(0x9e22c0, 0xc42031e600, 0xc4210c2b10, 0x22, 0x28, 0xa585d5496)
metrictank_1    |       /usr/local/go/src/runtime/hashmap_fast.go:306 +0x52b fp=0xc4216a7f18 sp=0xc4216a7eb8
metrictank_1    | github.com/raintank/metrictank/mdata/cache.(*CCache).Add(0xc4202fa070, 0xc4210c2b10, 0x22, 0x0, 0xc421875f82, 0x25, 0x25, 0xa585d5496)
metrictank_1    |       /home/mst/go/src/github.com/raintank/metrictank/mdata/cache/cache.go:77 +0x63 fp=0xc4216a7f80 sp=0xc4216a7f18
metrictank_1    | runtime.goexit()
metrictank_1    |       /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2086 +0x1 fp=0xc4216a7f88 sp=0xc4216a7f80
metrictank_1    | created by github.com/raintank/metrictank/api.(*Server).getSeries
metrictank_1    |       /home/mst/go/src/github.com/raintank/metrictank/api/dataprocessor.go:442 +0x122b
```

UPDATE: I recompiled with `-race` and now I'm getting a different error. This looks as if the `RWMutex` were completely ineffective because according to the backtraces the problem must be in the combination of the `evict` and `Add` methods.

```
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Read at 0x00c4201c81e0 by goroutine 215:
  runtime.mapaccess2_faststr()
      /usr/local/go/src/runtime/hashmap_fast.go:297 +0x0
  github.com/raintank/metrictank/mdata/cache.(*CCache).Add()
      /home/mst/go/src/github.com/raintank/metrictank/mdata/cache/cache.go:77 +0xaa

Previous write at 0x00c4201c81e0 by goroutine 155:
  runtime.mapdelete()
      /usr/local/go/src/runtime/hashmap.go:558 +0x0
  github.com/raintank/metrictank/mdata/cache.(*CCache).evict()
      /home/mst/go/src/github.com/raintank/metrictank/mdata/cache/cache.go:97 +0x30e
  github.com/raintank/metrictank/mdata/cache.(*CCache).evictLoop()
      /home/mst/go/src/github.com/raintank/metrictank/mdata/cache/cache.go:70 +0xb3

Goroutine 215 (running) created at:
  github.com/raintank/metrictank/api.(*Server).getSeries()
      /home/mst/go/src/github.com/raintank/metrictank/api/dataprocessor.go:442 +0x17c9
  github.com/raintank/metrictank/api.(*Server).getTarget()
      /home/mst/go/src/github.com/raintank/metrictank/api/dataprocessor.go:331 +0x9c3
  github.com/raintank/metrictank/api.(*Server).getTargetsLocal.func1()
      /home/mst/go/src/github.com/raintank/metrictank/api/dataprocessor.go:284 +0xa9

Goroutine 155 (running) created at:
  github.com/raintank/metrictank/mdata/cache.NewCCache()
      /home/mst/go/src/github.com/raintank/metrictank/mdata/cache/cache.go:63 +0x12f
  main.main()
      /home/mst/go/src/github.com/raintank/metrictank/metrictank.go:388 +0x246c
==================
```

Comment: Please include where exactly the race detector shows the read and write access.

Comment: Yeah, you built with the `-race` flag right? With that Go will tell you right where the problem is. Without it, you may be hitting some sort of worst-case corrupted memory detection error.

Comment: From this code I don't see any obvious problems. Except that this can't be all of the code, or why did you use a RWLock as only a simple Mutex? This code never read locks it. I suspect a goroutine or other structure has and is using a pointer to your map.

Comment: It might be something sneaky like passing a CCache object into a goroutine or a defer function through a closure, so you don't see how it got outside of a lock on first sight.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36167319/13422

Comment: It does look like a problem with the lock. One thing that can cause this is if you **ever, anywhere, made a COPY of that sync.RWMutex**. Don't ever do that.

Comment: You may want to try declaring `lock` as a pointer to a RWMutex which could solve a lock copy problem.

Comment: @ZanLynx you were totally right, I created a copy of the lock

Answer (score 2):

A colleague of mine has found the answer:

After calling `NewCCache()` I copied the returned variable by value (including the lock) and then called `Add()` on the copy, at the same time the `evictLoop()` go routine was still referring to the old copy. So they were operating on different copies of the lock :)